# Interactively building a "multiple-step" function using lambda functions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a function that is a fuction of "r" and takes two array of parameters `r0` and `V`, as well as `n` which is the number of elements of `r0`.

The function is defined such as : if `r` is below `r[0]`, return `V[0]`; if `r` is between `r[0]` and `r[1]`, return `V[1]` etc… and finally, if `r` is above `r[n]`, return `V[n+1]`. This illustrates the function when defined manually for n = 3:

[image: Multiple step function n = 3]

Here is a sample code I tried to do so using lambda functions:

```
n = 3
r0 = [10,30,60]
V = [1., -5. , 10., 3. ]

def makefn(r0, V):
    return lambda r : (V[0]-V[1])/2 if r < r0[0] else (V[1]-V[0])/2

for i in range(n):
    temp_function[i] = makefn(r0[i:i+1],V[i:i+2])

step_function = lambda r : (V[0]+V[-1])/2 + [temp_function[i](r) for i in range(n)]
```

The problems are : – I do not know how to pre-allocate a list of functions, so it returns " "temp_function" undefined." " – I do not know how to "add" functions so they combine there result.

Any idea on how to fix this code ?

Comment: why not just initialise `temp_function = []` and instead of `temp_function[i] = ...` in the loop, instead do `temp_function.append(...)`?

Comment: I did not think about it. Now it runs, but it still does no understand the final line, the sum of functions.